# How to use Wolfram Alpha to find a set of solutions that hold for any variables in the domain

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, wolframalpha, wolfram-language

Say that x and y are real numbers and y > 0. And say that I want to find for which values of A do (A + x + y > 0) and (A + x - y > 0) always hold, as long as x, y are in the domain.

How would I specify that on Wolfram Alpha? (Note: obviously these equations have no solution, but I just used it as an example.)

Or, if not on Wolfram, what software/website could I use?

I tried to write: solve for A: [input my first equation], y>0

but that didn't work, as it only gave integer solutions for when A, x, and y vary, instead of finding values of A such that it always holds no matter what x, y are.

Comment: Choose some equations that should have a solution and then try this way of entering those into WolframAlpha: `solve {A + x + y > 0, A + x - y > 0, y > 0} for A`  If that doesn't work then edit your equations into your post above and someone can see if they can find a way to get it to work. Sometimes finding the right form to get WA to solve something can be a bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28A+%2B+x+%2B+y+%3E+0%29+and+%28A+%2B+x+-+y+%3E+0%29+](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28A%20%2B%20x%20%2B%20y%20%3E%200%29%20and%20%28A%20%2B%20x%20-%20y%20%3E%200%29%20)

[x>-A, -A - x<y<A + x]

Comment: Please be more elaborate explaining the solution :)